# load R.drawable in function android

Tags: android, function, drawable, r.java-file

I have a function

```
 public void creacion_layout_items(R.drawable imagen_principal){
  LinearLayout _33_1_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_principal);                               
        ImageView imagen=new ImageView(this);   
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imagen_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(12,12);
        imagen.setLayoutParams(imagen_Params);
        imagen.setBackgroundResource(imagen_principal);
_33_1_layout.addView(imagen);
}
```

and I want to call the function

```
creacion_layout_items(R.drawable.all);
```

but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.drawable.something` is of `int` type. `R.drawable` is not type at all.
So use

```
public void creacion_layout_items(int yourResDrawableId){
   ...
 imagen.setBackgroundResource(yourResDrawableId);
   ...
}
```